# How to remove required field if the field is hidden state - Angular 2

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms

I need a solution for below mentioned issue. Kindly help to solve the problem.

**Case 1:**

Password is a required field only for new user Creation.

> Password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),

**Case 2:**

Changing the password visibility hidden using *ngIf

> ( "ng-reflect-ng-if":"false" )

**Case 3 :**

Now If i hit on Save its says Password required. help me to fix this issue field should not validate if it is hidden .

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `clearValidators()` and `setValidators()`, so whatever boolean flag you have for your hidden field, here I use `hidden`, and when that flag is `true`, the field is hidden.

You can do the following when you toggle that value:

```ts
this.hidden = !this.hidden
this.hidden ? this.myForm.get('Password').clearValidators() : 
              this.myForm.get('Password').setValidators([Validators.required])
this.myForm.get('Password').updateValueAndValidity();
```

DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/Jf2iTy5y3NMDNi5IDyoI?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot.It Worked for me.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Have a nice day and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a custom form validator. Custom validator can handle the validation based on your user scenarios.

Using custom validators would be the cleaner approach.

Refer: [Angular 2 custom validator](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Many thinks to learn from the Post.

Answer (score -2):

```
*ngIf="flase"
```

This how you can use *ngIf

Comment: Am fine with *ngIf. My issue is if the field is hidden, Am getting validation alert from form control.

Comment: please refer this.  https://plnkr.co/edit/Jf2iTy5y3NMDNi5IDyoI?p=preview

Comment: `ngIf` will not work since the validation is stored in the `FormGroup`, you can either use `clearValidators` & `setValidators` or write custom validation function.